# Formulate Controlled-Not as mapping (including modulo-2 addition)

Tags: quantum-gate, arithmetic

We often see that the controlled-not gate is written as
$CNOT |x y \rangle = |x\rangle |x \oplus y\rangle$.
Now, would it be possible to further expand this to get a general equation?

$$(\alpha_0 |0\rangle + \beta_0 |1\rangle) \otimes \left((\alpha_0 |0\rangle + \beta_0 |1\rangle) \oplus (\alpha_1 |0\rangle + \beta_1 |1\rangle) \right) \ ,$$

where $\oplus$ is XOR or modulo-2 addition.

However, expanding this to
$(\alpha_0 |0\rangle + \beta_0 |1\rangle) \otimes \left((\alpha_0 |0\rangle + \beta_0 |1\rangle) + (\alpha_1 |0\rangle + \beta_1 |1\rangle) \!\! \mod 2\right)$
does not seem right. Would this operator distribute? Does it behave the same way as in 'standard' algebra, i.e.

$$(\alpha_0 |0\rangle + \beta_0 |1\rangle) \otimes ((\alpha_0 + \alpha_1\!\!\!\mod 2)|0\rangle) + (\beta_0 + \beta_1 \!\!\! \mod 2) |1\rangle) \ ?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you point out, you have an $\oplus$ of ket vectors, which isn't well-defined, so we will need to define this operation somehow.

You definitely can't have $\beta_0+\beta_1\mod 2$ in a coefficient, since a quantum operator must be $\mathbb{C}$-linear, and there is no non-zero homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Whatever your operator is, its action is completely defined by any 4 basis vectors, such as $\vert 00\rangle, \vert 01\rangle, \vert 10\rangle$, and $\vert 11\rangle$. Thus, we want to have some sort of map that sends:
$$\begin{align}
\vert 00\rangle \mapsto& \vert 0\rangle(\vert 0\rangle \oplus \vert 0\rangle)\\
\vert 01\rangle \mapsto& \vert 0\rangle(\vert 0\rangle \oplus \vert 1\rangle)\\
\vert 10\rangle \mapsto& \vert 1\rangle(\vert 1\rangle \oplus \vert 0\rangle)\\
\vert 11\rangle \mapsto& \vert 1\rangle(\vert 1\rangle \oplus \vert 1\rangle)\\
\end{align}$$
for whatever you define $\oplus$ to be.

Since the operator must be unitary, and the original basis was orthogonal, we require $\vert 0\rangle \oplus \vert 0\rangle$ to be orthogonal to $\vert 0\rangle \oplus \vert 1\rangle$. In my mind, the only sensible way to way to define $\vert 0\rangle \oplus \vert 0\rangle$ would be as $\vert 0\rangle$. This forces $\vert 0\rangle \oplus \vert 1\rangle=\vert 1\rangle$.

From there, we ought to have that $\oplus$ is commutative, so $\vert 1\rangle \oplus \vert 0\rangle = \vert 0\rangle \oplus \vert 1\rangle = \vert 1\rangle$. Orthogonality then forces $\vert 1\rangle \oplus \vert 1\rangle= \vert 0 \rangle$ as well.

But, this means the operator *is* the CNOT operator. Basically, the CNOT is the most general form of the CNOT.

This reminds me of no-cloning: The no-cloning theorem states that you can't clone *arbitrary* states, but you can clone any given basis. However, once the action is defined on this basis, it's action on all other states is fixed.